# Jitter values for TCP Streams in Wireshark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

For the TCP stream, i want to get the Network Jitter values as shown for the RTP packets under RTP statistics as Max Jitter and Mean Jitter in Wireshark.

Is there any option in Wireshark which gives the Jitter values for a TCP stream.

I have only found graphs related to RTT, Throughput, Seq. no. and Windows scaling but nothing related to Jitter is there for TCP streams.

Anyone has idea how can i get the Jitter values in Wireshark for TCP stream?

Regards
Nitin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to calculate TCP jitter in Wireshark (or any other tool) but I assume that you could do this by comparing the deltas between the [TCP timestamp fields](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/tcp/option008.htm) and comparing to the actual arrival times.

You can export received timestamp values by adding a custom column with the expression **tcp.options.timestamp.tsval** then exporting as CSV or XML

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option is to export the timestamp columns to excel, create a pivot table and calculate the variance of the packets in a graphic to know what is the difference of time between the ordered packets.